# Psql refusing connections after restart

Tags: postgresql, psql

I began receiving these errors consistently after running a script that collects and stores data in psql:

> Could not connect because of FATAL:  remaining connection slots are
>   reserved for non-replication superuser connections

I am running psql on Ubuntu.  So I decided to restart psql with:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Now however, psql has shut down completely

```
Could not connect because of could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I am completely new to maintaining psql on a server and would be grateful for any advice.

Where do I even begin to solve this problem? How can I get psql to start again without losing any data that is in this massive database?

Comment: something is occupying all the connections.  connect at postgres (or other super-user) and do `select * from pg_stat_activity;` to see what's going on.

Comment: Consult the latest server logs inside /var/log/postgresql

Answer (score 1):

> I began receiving these errors consistently after running a script that collects and stores data in psql:

Your [`max_connections`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS) is too low, or that script isn't dying or releasing the connection.

If you're getting `Connection refused` after you restart, then perhaps you have multiple copies of `postgresql` installed on the same machine and you mean to connect to a different port (like 5433). If you're using Ubuntu or Debian run `pg_lsclusters` and paste the output.

Comment: Thanks , how can I modify max connections to increase the maximum

Comment: @the_darkside edit your postgresql.conf https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS